# Problem in displaying images from local storage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, angular6

i'm new to angular framework and not used to web development. I couldn't able to display the images stored in local storage.

```
<tr *ngFor = "let item of unused; let i = index ; ">
     <div   style="padding-left:25%;padding-top:0%;"  class="row">
          <img  src="" id="imageID{{i}}" style ="width: 100%;height: 100%;padding-right: 50px;padding-bottom: 15px;" >
     </div>
</tr>
```

I declared the array variable globally and also used in ngOnit like this

```
unused=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

```
for (let i=0; i<5;i++)
    { 
      var n = i.toString();

      var dataImage = localStorage.getItem(("image"+ n));
      var bannerImg = document.getElementById(("imageID"+n)) as HTMLImageElement;
      bannerImg.src = dataImage;
    }
```

Comment: Your code need much more improvement. This is not a proper angular code. For your scenario. Create an array objects and add image path into that. Loop through that object in html and use it in src tag directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataImages: any[]= [];

ngOnInit(){
for (let i=0; i<5;i++)
    { 
      var dataImage = localStorage.getItem(("image"+ i));
      dataImages.push(dataImage);
    }
}

<tr *ngFor = "let item of dataImages">
     <div   style="padding-left:25%;padding-top:0%;"  class="row">
          <img  [src]="item"  style ="width: 100%;height: 100%;padding-right: 50px;padding-bottom: 15px;" >
     </div>
</tr>
```